# Custom field to array?

Tags: custom-field, get-posts, array

I have a posts query that queries posts by ID but want to select those posts by enetering a custom field. Here is the query and where I want to put the custom field:

```
$query_args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'include' => '483,454, CUSTOM FIELD HERE', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC');
```

More info: Custom field is listids and passed in include. But doesn't work.

```
<?php
&listids = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'list_array', true);
$query_args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'include' => 'echo $listids;', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC');
$query_posts = get_posts($query_args);
$last_query = end($query_posts);
foreach ($query_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
```

Comment: Did you try and search in Google, WordPress handles custom fields in for a query already, http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: That's why `meta_query` is for. Please search on the site.

Comment: No, there is n instructions anywhere for passing the custom field value into an array.

Comment: Right in the link it says `meta_query (array)` and `value (string|array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you(or users) will enter post ids into a posts custom field, comma separated, eg: `11,13,34,54` OR `11, 13, 34, 54`.

Then all you need to do is get the custom field value for the loaded post, explode the custom field value by comma(,): and, then you'll have a nice array to pass into the `include` parameter. Here is an example showing the important pieces:

```
<?php
    $postIds = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'postIds', true); // get custom field value
    $arrayIds = explode(',', $postIds); // explode value into an array of ids
    if(count($arrayIds) <= 1) // if array contains one element or less, there's spaces after comma's, or you only entered one id
    {
        if( strpos($arrayIds[0], ',') !== false )// if the first array value has commas, there were spaces after ids entered
        {
            $arrayIds = array(); // reset array
            $arrayIds = explode(', ', $postIds); // explode ids with space after comma's
        }

    }

    $args = array(
        'include' => $arrayIds // pass array of ids into `include` parameter
    );
    ...
?>
```

Comment: I thank you very much as this has worked perfectly. You're awesome.